# Meaning of a sentence from The Emperor's New Clothes

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I read the story "The Emperor's New Clothes". One sentence I do not understand. Of course, they could see perfectly well that the crafty pair was only pretending to weave the cloth, and cut it, and stitch it. But they didn't dare disclose the truth to the emperor.***Disagreeing with the emperor*** would be like confessing that they had poor taste.

I don't understand "disagreeing with the emperor" in this sentence.

Comment: Look up the meaning of "agree", then of "disagree". Consider what might happen to someone who *disagrees* with a country's ruler.

Comment: This sentence means ministers disagreeing with the emperor would be like confessing that they had poor taste, right?

Comment: Yes. _If they were to disagree with the emperor, it would be like confessing that they had poor taste._ (I thought the impostors had said that people who couldn't see the cloth were no good at their jobs?)